# How to use logical method to replace values that are in specific range

Tags: matlab, boolean-logic

I wanted to replace the values within specific range to its positive values, something like:

```
X(X<a && X>b)=abs(X(X<a && X>b))
```

However I get error saying that

> Operands to the || and && operators must be convertible to logical
>   scalar values.

Any ideas how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Replace `&&` with `&`. The use of `&&` if for conditions, not for indexing.

Comment: @Adiel Why dont you add your comment as an answer?

Comment: 1. I convinced there already an answer for that over here, 2. Don't think that little sentence should be an answer. 3. If you want to elaborate this to an answer, with  links, implications, etc., you welcome

Comment: Can't believe I made such mistake. But what's the different between `&&` and `&` in this context? Usually we will use `&&` in `if` statement, this is an exception? As I understood, `&&` will force check the condition after `&&`.

Comment: Okay few seconds behind hahaha